# How to remove dict that have duplicate val?

Tags: python

In file:

```
A01,rose
C15,tiger
C02,cat
B03,rose
```

I tried to make them into dict, but I am stuck as I am not sure how to remove the duplicate val from dict.

```
with fop as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.strip().split(',')
       d[str(key)] = val
```

Any suggestion?

Expected to get:

```
C15,tiger
C02,cat
```

Comment: You mean delete the entries which are duplicates? So not leaving 1 of those?

Comment: Please show what you have attempted and explain why it doesn't work, then ask a question.

Comment: @RvdK Yes, I want to delete entries that are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary keys are by default unique so you could use that property to make this work better.

Something like this should do the trick (although you'll have to reverse the keys/values for your output but I'll leave that as an exercise to you):

```
d = {}
with fop as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.strip().split(',')
        d[val] = key

print d.items()
```

Note that this gives 1 key per value, if you're simply looking for removing any duplicate item it will be slightly different (but similar):

```
d = {}
duplicates = {}
with fop as f:
    for line in f:
       key, val = line.strip().split(',')
       if val in d:
           duplicates[val] = True
       d[val] = key

for duplicate in duplicates:
    del d[duplicate]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, he wants none of the entries which are duplicate in the file.

Comment: @RvdK I tried your codes but I got 'NameError: name 'd' is not defined', any suggestion?

Comment: You had a `d` in your original question, I expected that it would still be there ;)

Comment: @ThanaDaray: The code is from Wolph, I just commented.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a track of which value you have seen when building your dictionary:

```
seen = set()
d = dict()

with open('some-file') as f:
   for line in f:
      if line.strip():
          for key,value in line.split(','):
             if value not in seen:
                 d[key] = value
                 seen.add(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# turn the data into a dictionary
with fop as f:
    data = dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
```

Dictionaries can be made by passing a list or iterable of tuples to the `dict` builtin. This makes turning you data into a dictionary very simple.

```
from collections import Counter

# extract unique values
value_counts = Counter(data.values())
unique_values = set(value for value, count in value_counts.items() if count == 1)
unique_data = dict((key, value) for key, value in data.items() 
        if value in unique_values)
```

The `Counter` class is dictionary that counts the number of times values occur in an iterable. We can then extract the values that have a count of 1 and use that to create a new dictionary with all the unique values.